# InputMismatchException not being caught at all

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to make a calculator where people have different choices, based on numbers.

When I put in a choice that is not an int, it throws a InputMismatchException, but for some reason it won't be caught.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean run = true;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;
        while (run) {
            System.out.println("Bem-vindo a calculadora! Escolha uma das opções abaixo!");
            System.out.println("1. Conversor binario");
            System.out.println("2. Conversor octal");
            System.out.println("3. Conversor decimal");
            System.out.println("4. Conversor hexadecimal");
            System.out.println("5. Calculadora de binario");
            System.out.println("6. Calculadora de octal");
            System.out.println("7. Calculadora normal");
            System.out.println("8. Calculadora de hexadecimal");
            System.out.println("9. Sair");
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter a number");
                choice = in.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please put in a Valid Number");
                choice = 0;
                choice = in.nextInt();
            }
            
            switch (choice) {
            case 1: 

            case 2:

            case 3:

            case 4:

            case 5:
            
            case 6:
                
            case 7:
                
            case 8:
                
            case 9:
                run = false;
                break;
                
            default:
                System.out.println("Input incorreto. Tente novamente.");
                choice = in.nextInt();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have three times `in.nextInt()` in your code, but yet you have a single associated `catch` block.

Comment: @MCEmperor Would you recommend I take out the last one?

Comment: What if you enter not-a-number the second time as well? You need to use a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider this solution:

make `Scanner in` as the class field,

move start info souts and switch service to another method (without any loop), that throws InputMismatchException, ex.:

```
public class Calculator {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static void calc() throws InputMismatchException {
         int choice = 0;
         System.out.println("Bem-vindo a calculadora! Escolha uma das opções abaixo!");
         ...
         System.out.println("Enter a number");
         choice = in.nextInt();

         switch (choice) {

         case 1:
            System.out.println("entered=" + choice);
            break;
         ...
         default:
            System.out.println("Input incorreto. Tente novamente.");
            break;
         }
    }
```

and run it in the loop with try - catch statement, ex.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean ok = true;
    while (ok) {
        try {
            calc();
            ok = false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("InputMismatchException " + e.getMessage());
            in.nextLine();
        }
    }
    in.close();
}
```

-- edit --

but of course throws InputMismatchException could ommitted in `calc()` method, because it is Unchecked exception